# Como instalar node.js em hospedagem compartilhada (CPanel)?

Tags: node.js, hospedagem

**DESCRIÇÂO:**
Tenho uma hospedagem compartilhada (CPanel) e quero instalar node.js nesta hospedagem para que eu possa assim instalar o **[GHOST](https://ghost.org/)**, ferramenta ótima pra gerenciar artigos, sem a necessidade de basear todo meu projeto em um CMS como Joomla ou Wordpress.

**PROBLEMA:**
Hospedagens compartilhadas não possuem node.js de forma nativa.

**PERGUNTA:**
Se possível, como instalar node.js em uma hospedagem compartilhada que utilizada CPanel?

**ALTERNATIVA:**
Algum outra ferramenta que faça o mesmo que o Ghost, mas que não use plataforma node.js e que seja tão simples quanto o Ghost.

Comment: Geralmente as hospedagens compartilhadas não te deixam instalar nada, pois você precisaria de permissão de root para isso.

Comment: Só o seu serviço de hospedagem pode instalar o node.js em hospedagem compartilhada, e raramente eles fazem isso, a maioria só dá permissão para você instalar em servidores dedicados...

Comment: Já tentou utilizar o https://www.heroku.com/ ?

Comment: @AlexandreStrevenski "Infelizmente alguns servidores cloud específicos para utilizar o Node.js como o Nodejitsu & Heeroku NÃO são compatíveis com o Ghost. Eles irão funcionar no início, mas irão deletar seus arquivos, imagens e seu banco de dados irá desaparecer. O Heroku suporta MySQL e você pode usa-lo, porém você ainda assim irá perder suas imagens enviadas."  http://docs.ghost.org/pt-BR/installation/deploy/

Comment: A ferramenta alternativa seria o Wordpress. Apesar de ter algumas falhas de segurança, apresenta melhor compatibilidade. Pra usar o node.js o ideal é ter um servidor vps ou cloud com licença de cPanel, assim pode customizar livremente os módulos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não recomendo,
mas você pode seguir [este tutorial](http://increaseyourgeek.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/install-node-js-without-using-sudo/).

```
./configure --prefix=/home/seu_user_name
```